# HTTPClient GetAsync post object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

We currently have a generic MVC method that GET's data from ASP.NET Web API

```
 public static T Get<T>(string apiURI, object p)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Config.API_BaseSite);

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(apiURI).Result;


            // Check that response was successful or throw exception  
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode == false)
            {
                string responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                throw new HttpException((int)response.StatusCode, responseBody);
            }

            T res = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result;
            return (T)res;
        }
    }
```

Our question is:- obviously, we can not send 'p' as you would with a post,

```
  client.PostAsync(apiURI, new StringContent(p.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
```

but how we go about sending this object / JSON with a get. 
We have seen sending it as part of the URL, however, is there an alternative?

Comment: Using .Result under an ASP.Net runtime host will cause you a world of pain.

Comment: @Darrel Miller could you elaborate please. What are the issues of using this?

Comment: The Syncronization context of ASP.Net runtime only supports a single thread running at once, which is why you can access statics like HttpContext.  However, when you do .Result it blocks the executing thread.  If any of the code in the async method tries to access HttpContext you will deadlock.  To quote Brad Wilson, a dev on the ASP.NET team "Using .Result or .Wait (or anything related) in an ASP.NET pipeline will cause deadlocks. I guarantee it."

Comment: @DarrelMiller Thanks Darrel, will take this in consideration. What would the alternative be then to obtain the result from the webAPI call?

Comment: You either have to use async/await or .ContinueWith(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GET** sends the values with the query string (end of url), in regards to "but how we go about sending this object / JSON with a get. We have seen sending it as part of the URL, however, is there an alternative?".

The alternative is **POST** or **PUT**.

**PUT** is best used when the user creates the key/url. You can look at examples such as cnn.com - where the URL's are just short versions of the article title. You want to PUT a page at that URL.

Example: 
http://newday.blogs.cnn.com/2014/03/19/five-things-to-know-for-your-new-day-wednesday-march-19-2014/?hpt=hp_t2

has the url of "five-things-to-know-for-your-new-day-wednesday-march-19-2014", which was generated from the article title of "Five Things to Know for Your New Day – Wednesday, March 19, 2014"

In general, you should follow these guidelines:

Use **GET** when you want to fetch data from the server. Think of search engines. You can see your search query in the query string. You can also book mark it. It doesn't change anything on the server at all.

Use **POST** when you want to create a resource.

Use **PUT** when you want to create resources, but it also overwrites them. If you PUT an object twice, the servers state is only changed once. The opposite is true for POST

Use **DELETE** when you want to delete stuff

Neither POST nor PUT use the query string. GET does

Comment: Both POST and PUT can use the query string as well as the body.